# Pressure difference between two connected bodies of water

Tags: pressure, water

My friend has a large swimming pool connected to a much smaller jacuzzi tub.  Both bodies are filled to the same water level.  There is a hole about 1” diameter between the two about 18” below water surface.  It was observed that the cooler water from the swimming pool kept flowing into the hotter jacuzzi tub.  We assumed that both bodies would have the same pressure because they were filled to the same level.  Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that water "keeps flowing" into the jacuzzi implies that water is somehow being removed from the jacuzzi, or else it would eventually wind up with a higher water level than the pool, and finally overflow. As water is removed from the jacuzzi (by  evaporation, or splashing from the bubbles, or people constantly getting in and out), water from the pool must flow in to fill it. I'm not really convinced that you've accurately measured that the water levels are truly equal, either, as merely entering either the pool or the jacuzzi will change the water level.

Comment: Yes, there is water being removed from the jacuzzi, heated and returned via a pump to jacuzzi jets

Comment: @KurtWiesenberger I'm talking about net removal, taking some water out and putting the same amount back in wouldn't have an effect. If water really is continually flowing from the pool into the jacuzzi, it must be going *somewhere*.

Answer (score 0):

The density of the warmer water is probably less, so the pressure may be somewhat different for the same level. The question is why the system does not achieve equilibrium. Maybe warm water evaporates faster.